# How Do I Pay for a User's Ride?

Tags: uber-api

I want to use the Uber API to initiate a trip for a user. However, I want to pay for the trip (using my preset pickup and drop-off locations). It would be acceptable to launch a ride request with a prepaid promotional credit of my ride budget.

Is this possible in the Uber APIs? I appears that the payment methods endpoint returns payment methods for the rider. It also appears that the payment_method_id  option to the ride request endpoint wants a rider's payment method.

Is there a way I can initiate a trip to/from preset locations, while also ensuring that I pay (up to) $XX for the trip?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There is not any publicly available way to do this currently. The Uber Developer platform are working on making this option available. I am not able to share any timeline on that, but it is indeed being worked on.

In the meantime, I would direct you to non-API solutions that may in some way fit into your use-case of paying for another user's uber ride:

```
https://www.uber.com/events
https://uber-central.com/
https://www.uber.com/business/
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: thanks for your response, very helpful. UberCENTRAL looks like it might fit the bill, but there's no response there. Could you share any guidance on the best way to get in touch with someone who could help us get started?

Comment: Sorry, meant to tag you on this @KyleDavis.